# Java cast method

Tags: java, guava, apache-commons

I am not sure if this question belongs here. I have written the following method to cast an object to a particular type.

```
private static <T> T cast(Object obj) {
    return (T) (obj);
}
```

I am wondering why I do not find such method in Guava or Apache Commons? Am I missing something?

Thanks,

Venk

Comment: Why do you want that method in the first place?

Comment: Because that method is a) a no-op, due to type erasure, and b) is not actually noticeably shorter than actually doing the cast?

Comment: I agree with the first part. It is noticably shorter if you are using Maps?

Comment: What would you expect such a method to actually do?  Casting an object doesn't change it in any way - it's not type conversion.  It simply tells the compiler that it's OK to use that object in a circumstance where an expression of a different type is expected.  So it's a "compiler trick"; and doing it at run-time makes no sense.

Comment: @HollisWaite: It is shorter in most cases, provided you're assigning to a variable when you use it. For example, `SomeLongClassName foo = cast(someObject);` vs. `SomeLongClassName foo = (SomeLongClassName) someObject;`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use standart [cast](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29) method with method

```
SomeClass o = SomeClass.class.cast(obj);
```

No reason to use your method

```
SomeClass o = Utils.<SomeClass>cast(obj);
```

Comment: There is also the builtin cast:  SomeClass o = (Someclass)blammo;

Comment: @DwB Author not looking for easy ways:)

Comment: @Ilya: With the method suggested in the question, the code would look like `SomeClass o = Utils.cast(obj);`... the type is inferred from the target of the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is not typesave. Guava in particular is designed to utilize javas static typing to the maximum. With your method it would be possible to cast an object of any class to an object of any other class. This is not supposed to be done.

if you would try the following

```
Integer a = (Integer) "1";
```

the compiler would rightfully complain. If you'd use your cast method you would just get rid of the compilation error and postpone the error to runtime. Which is never a good idea. Additionally the compiler warns you that the cast to T is unchecked and may cause problems later on.

In most cases the java type inference is pretty solid and you should listen to compiler warnings.

Reflection on the other hand discards the java type systeme nearly completely. Dealing with this is a little tricky but there are ways to check if types are compatible (eg. `Class.isAssignableFrom(Class)`).